# error in xpstar90.dll at the time of database creation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm facing the problem when i am creating database in SQL server management studio 2008. it is showing error that xpstar90.dll DLL find could not load (response 126).

Answer (score 0):

This error usually indicates the dll in question got corrupted. You can try to replace it with a dll from another computer running the same version of SQL Server.

Comment: thanks for the appropriate answer its really work and i solved my problem..thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

Another reason I found for this is that the user does not have access to one of the directories containing xpstar90.dll.  In my case, when the admin added management studio to my PC, she did not enable read access to C:\program files\Microsoft Sql Server\MSSQL.1.  That being the case, it generated the error that it could not find xpstar90.dll even though it was on the machine.